# Async accept an ssl socket using asio and c++

Tags: c++, ssl, asynchronous, boost-asio, asio

I am trying to write an async server using asio with SSL encrypted sockets. Currently I have code that does not use SSL, and after following [this](https://dens.website/tutorials/cpp-asio/ssl-tls) tutorial I have a basic idea of how to accept an SSL socket, however I do not know how to adapt this code to accept an SSL connection:

```cpp
void waitForClients() {

    acceptor.async_accept(
        [this](std::error_code ec, asio::ip::tcp::socket socket) {
            if (!ec) {
                Conn newConn = std::make_shared<Connection>(ctx, std::move(socket));
                connections.push_back(newConn);

            } else {
                std::cerr << "[SERVER] New connection error: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            }
            waitForClients();
        }
    );
}

//this is how the tutorial shows to accept a connection
ssl_socket socket(io_context, ssl_context);
acceptor.accept(socket.next_layer());
```

The issue is that the callback for `acceptor.async_accept` gives an ordinary `asio::ip::tcp::socket` rather than an `asio::ssl::ssl_socket<asio::ip::tcp::socket>`, and I cannot find any documentation that suggests there is a method of `async_accept`ing an SSL socket in such a way. The only method I have seen is to construct a socket first then accept it afterwards, which cannot be done in this asynchronous manner.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you already have code that does that for a non-SSL socket, you can just use the same things to accept the SSL socket. If the question is about how to use threads or writing asynchronous code in general in c++, then drop all the sockets and asio stuff from your question and make a basic example of starting/joining a thread. If none of those apply, you should clarify your question.

Comment: @super I have attempted to add clarification to my question but I am not entirely certain what is unclear, if there's anything specific it would be nice to know.

Comment: I've never used this myself, but a quick glance at the documentation tells shows `typedef ssl::stream<tcp::socket> ssl_socket;`. So the `ssl_socket` in this case is just a wrapper around a normal socket. So a normal socket is what you want. Just wrap it in an `ssl::stream.`

Comment: @super I wasn't sure if I could construct an `ssl_socket` from an existing socket rather than accepting a connection to an `ssl_socket` directly. But it is worth a try

Comment: I don't really see the issue. In `acceptor.accept(socket.next_layer());` you pass in the socket to `accept`. Why can't you just do the same thing for `async_accept`?

Comment: @super since `async_accept` does not take a socket as an argument, it passes the socket to the callback function after creating it itself. therefore I cannot pass `socket.next_layer()` to it because `socket` doesn't exist yet

Comment: Look to me that is has [several overloads](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept.html) where you can pass in the socket.

Comment: @super I did see that however I fail to see how I can use that. If I have the socket as a local variable, it will go out of scope and fail, however if I have it as a member of the class or global, only one client will be able to connect at once

Comment: Ok. So your question is then not about anything with sockets or asio. It's not about asynchronous code either. It's about how to manage the lifetime of objects. What you normally do is use a `std::vector` or similar container and store all the connections in there. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would the fact that you get the socket passed back to you in the callable help solve your issue addressed in your last comment? It's really one of the most core concepts of programming, how to manage lifetime of objects and scope. How is this not mentioned in your question until 5 back-and-forths of probing questions in the comments?

Comment: @super see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by realising that the second argument to the constructor of `asio::ssl::stream<asio::ip::tcp::socket>` is *any* initialiser for the underlying type `asio::ip::tcp::socket`. Thus the problem can be solved:

```cpp
void waitForClients() {
    acceptor.async_accept(
        [this](std::error_code ec, asio::ip::tcp::socket socket) {
            if (!ec) {
                //initialise an ssl stream from already created socket
                asio::ssl::stream<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sslStream(sslCtx, std::move(socket);
                //then pass it on to be used
                Conn newConn = std::make_shared<Connection>(ctx, sslStream);
                connections.push_back(newConn);

            } else {
                std::cerr << "[SERVER] New connection error: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            }
            waitForClients();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I was just trying to reason with you from the information you where giving in the comments. *You* said it was about managing lifetime. I only spelled it out for you. I'm pretty sure this is exactly what my second comment told you. But hey, great job on solving it.

Comment: Leaving a comment to help others in the future: It seems the order of arguments for the ssl::stream initializer has been swapped around (?), so the std::move(socket) would now need to come before the context